# How do I terminate a subprocess when it creates a particular file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am running python's subprocess to use an exe as part of some automated tests. Everything seems to run great but the call rarely terminates on its own and my runs often hang for the full 45 mins. Typically the exe should only run 10-20 mins and output a summary file. This exe does generate a complete output file (Effectively finishing its job) and then just goes on hanging. I'm wondering how to call a conditional subprocess that would terminate when the file appears.

```
timeout = 2700  # how many seconds to wait  for exe to finish (2700 = 45mins)
try:
    p = subprocess.run(cmd_split, timeout=timeout)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print(f'Timeout for exe({timeout}s) expired')
```

Adding the timeout has been great and allowed tests to continue. That's as far as I've gotten

Comment: Switch from `run` to `Popen` so you're no longer blocking, and use any of the _many_ filesystem-monitoring libraries to use whichever interface the local operating system provides to be notified when the file in question is closed after write. Or keep blocking but do the filesystem monitoring in a thread (or block in the foreground and do the filesystem-monitoring in a thread, your choice)

Comment: (the traditional filesystem notification interface for Linux is/was `inotify`, if that helps you search re: Python libraries that wrap it and its alternatives/competitors).